# How many garlands can be made with 4 identical red flowers and 3 identical white flowers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

By the formula of [Circular permutations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html) , the number of ways of arranging 7 flowers should be $6!$ . But in a garland, the sense of clockwise/anti-clockwise is same so that the number of ways become $\frac{6!}{2}$.

Also , since we have 4 alike flowers of one kind and 3 alike flowers of other kind , the final answer should be $\frac{6!}{3!4!2}$ which is equal to $2.5$. However , by manually counting , it appears that there are only 4 possible garlands ( see figure below). What mistake have I done ?

[image: meow]

Comment: "But in a garland, the sense of clockwise/anti-clockwise is same so that the number of ways become"  But that assumes no garland is its own mirror image

Comment: @fleablood Thanks sir. But why ?

Comment: "But why ? " But why what?

Comment: If you say you are going to divide by two, you are assuming you actually counting to things that are the same seperately.  If you are only counting them once you *don't divide by two.  If something is its own mirror image you are counting it only once.

Answer (score 1):

Note that most of those garlands are actually mirror symmetric. So if you, for a second, pretend that you aren't allowed to flip a garland over, you will get $5$ distinct garlands, both from your computation and from your drawings.

The moment you allow yourself to flip them over, only a single pair of the 5 become equal.

Comment: The argument of mirror symmetric is same as of ignoring sense of clockwise/anticlockwise.

Comment: How can I get 5 drawings ? Can you please tell me the fifth one which I missed to draw ? Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant The mirror image of the rightmost garland (or equivalently, the result of flipping it upside-down) is the fifth one.

Comment: The mirror image of right most one will exactly look like what the right most will look like if viewed from behind the board. They should be same them.  A garland doesn't change depending from which side am I looking at it.

Comment: @An_Elephant "So if you, for a second, pretend that you **aren't allowed to flip a garland over**, you will get 5
 distinct garlands" It does in this imaginary world I have created in my answer. However, the first 3 _actually_ doesn't change if you flip them over: they actually look identical before and after. If you leave the room, and I flip some of them over, you wouldn't be able to tell which ones I flipped, apart from the rightmost one. That is why your division by 2 is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you write “only”. Your count yielded $2.5$, not $5$, so you counted too few, not too many garlands.

The problem with your count is that a reflection is a permutation iff the garland has mirror symmetry. So if you account for both reflections and permutations (yielding $2.5$), you’re overcounting symmetries because you’re double-counting all the symmetries that are both a permutation and a reflection; and if you account only for permutations (yielding $5$), you’re undercounting the symmetries because you’re not counting the reflections that aren’t permutations, i.e. the reflections of the garlands that don’t have mirror symmetry. As Arthur points out in their answer, only the rightmost garland doesn’t have mirror symmetry, so in this case you can divide out the permutations, leaving $5$ garlands (including the rightmost one in the image and its mirror image) and then subtract out the one garland you double-counted because the mirror image is considered equivalent.

For larger problems where you don’t want to check by hand how the permutations of flowers interact with the geometric symmetries, you can use the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem). In the present case, we can assign weight $0$ to red and weight $1$ to yellow and count the garlands of weight $3$. Then the colour generating function is $f(t)=1+t$. The cycle index of the group of rotations and reflections acting on the $7$ flowers is

$$
Z(t_1,t_2,t_7)=\frac1{14}\left(t_1^7+7t_1t_2^3+6t_7\right)
$$

since the identity has $7$ fixed points, each of the $7$ reflections has $1$ fixed point and $3$ cycles of length $2$, and each of the $6$ rotations has $1$ cycle of length $7$. The theorem yields the generating function for the number of garlands by weight,

\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x)
&=&
Z\left(f(x),f\left(x^2\right),f\left(x^7\right)\right)
\\
&=&
Z\left(1+x,1+x^2,1+x^7\right)
\\
&=&
\frac1{14}\left((1+x)^7+7(1+x)\left(1+x^2\right)^3+6\left(1+x^7\right)\right)
\\
&=&
1+x+3x^2+4x^3+4x^4+3x^5+x^6+x^7\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

It tells us not only that there are indeed $4$ garlands of weight $3$ (i.e. with $3$ yellow and $4$ red flowers) but also the numbers of garlands for all other weights: $1$ garland with only red flowers, $1$ garland with a single yellow flowers, and $3$ garlands with two yellow flowers (corresponding to the three different distances the two yellow flowers can have from each other). (The remaining counts correspond to the same cases with red and yellow swapped.)

Comment: Thanks but Unfortunately, I am a beginner in permutations and combinations. So your answer went above my head.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the formula

*No. of circular permutations of n objects = (No. of linear permutations of n objects)/n*
when the 'n' objects are DISTINCT

You'll have to do it manually only (like *Sachin Sir* did)

What you did is, calculated linear permutations as 7!/(4!3!) and divided it by 7 *(as n! is divided by n in orginal formula to get (n-1)!)*

Then used the logic that since anticlockwise and clockwise arrangements are same (as the garland is flippable & flowers appear identical from both faces), you divided it by 2

And finally got (7-1)!/(3!4!)(2)

Now consider this,

Let the 2 different flowers be Rose & Marigold (denoted by R & M respectively)

For a smaller number, let's assume we have 2 flowers of each of these varieties

So number of linear permutations= 4!/(2!2!)=6

They are as follows:

**(1)** R R M M
**(2)** M M R R
**(3)** R M M R
**(4)** M R R M
**(5)** R M R M
**(6)** M R M R

As you know, if any of the above linear arrangements read the same when all of them are read from *left to right* **in a LOOP** (or you can choose *right to left*, but choose only 1 direction. I chose *left to right* for convenience), then they form the same circular permutation.

Clearly, **RRMM** reads the same as **RMMR** when read starting from 2nd character & the same as **MMRR** when read starting from the 3rd character & **MRRM** when read starting from the 4th character (in loop)

So all 4 of them are equivalent

Similarly, **RMRM** reads the same as **MRMR** when read starting from the 2nd/4th character in loop

So essentially, there are *only **2*** unique circular arrangements, which can be taken as **RRMM** & **RMRM**

No worries of dividing by 2 to eliminate double counting of same arrangement in clockwise and anticlockwise direction (which we do for flowers in a garland or beads in a necklace) as **RRMM & RMRM** are still different from each other when read from *left to right* as **MMRR & MRMR**

The correct answer here is **2** and not (4-1)!/(2!2!)(2) *(which is not even an integer btw)* as calculated by your method

You can do the same for the 35 [=7!/(3!4!)] linear arrangements formed in your case

Basically, the conclusion is, the only way to do this Question is to do it manually by arranging the flowers on the circle

Firstly, take 4 of the same kind together, then take 3 of the (any one of the two) same kind together then 2 of same kind together and so on...

*Best of luck for JEE*

Comment: Thanks for explaining with a simpler example. I understand that when items are not distinct , we'll have to count manually.

Comment: But you didn't explained why using formula is theoretically wrong ?

Comment: The logic behind the original formula is, for eg, you have 4 ppl, namely  **A,B,C & D**.  Now, when you keep their order fixed as *ABCD* ON A CIRCLE (in either one of CW/ACW direction) you'll get 4 linear arrangements for this particular order, namely, *ABCD, BCDA* (when u start naming from 2nd person), *CDAB & DABC*. So 4 **(=n)** (no. of distinct characters) linear permutations account for **1** circular permutation hence **n!** linear permutations account for **n!/n = (n-1)!** circular permutations. It won't go this way if all the objects are NOT DISTINCT

Comment: But do remember, in above proof, read all cases in *ONLY* one direction on the circle, either CW **or** ACW. Don't say that 1 circular permutation accounts for 2n linear permutations by counting ACW **&** CW linear arrangements for the same circular permutation, as when *A,B,C&D* are people, direction *matters* (this is why we divide by 2 as n!/2n in case of beads bcz they are flippable and identical from both faces, so direction *doesn't matter*)

Comment: If all objects are NOT DISTINCT, some linear permutations u get from a particular circular permutation by changing the starting point *may not be different* from each other. So we can't say 1 circular permutation in CW/ACW sense accounts for exactly 'n' different linear permutations